# Make Infragistics Ultragrid look "Disabled"

Tags: .net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a legacy .NET WinForms application that needs a modification. We're using an Infragistics `UltraGrid` to display some information. The new requirement is that the grid must be "read-only" in certain circumstances.  To that end, I've successfully set the `grdMain.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowUpdate`, `grdMain.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowDelete` and `grdMain.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowAddNew` properties so that the grid is "read-only".  But now I need to change the appearance of the grid so that it looks disabled.  And this is where my trouble lies. I want to be able to toggle the grid's cell text and cell background color, etc. between looking enabled and disabled.

> NOTE:  I tried actually disabling the grid with `grdMain.Enabled` but
> when the grid is disabled, users cannot do "anything" with it like
> resize columns or highlight & copy text.  So that was a bust.

I think I could brute force this and iterate bands and columns or rows and manually set colors, but it seems to me like Infragistics would have though of something like this and there should be a more graceful way of going about it. Any information you can provide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [Activation](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawingrid~infragistics.win.ultrawingrid.activation) of either each row, each column or each cell in the grid in order to disable it. Keep in mind if you do so the users will not be able to select cells, nor the cells' text. The cells will be disabled - no highlight or copy text will be allowed.

Other approach you can take is set the cells' appearance. To set the appearance to all cells at once you can use CellAppearance of the Override object like this:

```
ultraGrid.DisplayLayout.Override.CellAppearance.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
```

Comment: Thank you, this was it.  Actually, I had tried this, originally.  My *real* problem was that there was some code hiding in a place where it shouldn't have been (poor object-oriented coding) that was setting individual columns' `BackColor` settings.  And the column settings were overriding the grid settings.